# how to access jsonarray elemennts

Tags: java, json

```
 @Path("/getVersion")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getVersion(String getVersionJson) {
        String version = "", patches = "", connectionStatus = "", output1 = "", output2 = "";

        try {

            JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject(getVersionJson);

            String ip = inputJson.getString("ipaddress").trim();

            String userName = inputJson.getString("username").trim();
            String passWord = inputJson.getString("password").trim();
            connectionStatus = getSSHConnection(ip, userName, passWord);

            if (connectionStatus.equals("Connected")) {

                //Version Check
                expect.send("bwshowver" + "\n");
                if (expect.expect("$") > -1) {
                    String contt = "";
                    contt = (expect.before);
                    if (contt != null && contt != "") {

                        contt = contt.replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
                        contt = contt.replaceAll(" +", " ");

                        String splitter[] = contt.split("\n");

                        for (int i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {
//                         
                            if (splitter[i].contains("Patches")) {
                                patches = splitter[i];
                            }
                            //version
                            if (splitter[i].contains("version")) {
                                version = splitter[i];
                            }
//                            output1=version.toString();
//                            output2=patches.toString();
//                             output3=output1+output2;
//                                     
                            output1 = contt;
                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    output1 = "Error in version check";
                    System.out.println("Error in version check");
                }

            } else {
                output1 = connectionStatus;
                System.out.println(connectionStatus);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            output1 = "Error";
            //     logger.error("Exception in getVersion Function-ServService Class: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            stopSSH();
        }

        return output3;
    }
```

//The string which is being passed from getVersion comprises of

```
[{"ipaddress":"10.253.140.116","password":"c0mcast!","username":"bwadmin"},{"ipaddress":"10.253.140.117","password":"bwadmin!","username":"bwadmin"}]
```

//My requirement is to access the value of ipaddress and password and username and store items in an array and send them to ConnectionStatus.

Comment: You already got all what you need apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(getVersionJson);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    //Now you can fetch values from each JSON Object
}
```

`JSONObject` class represents just one JSON. This is generally inside braces `{` and  `}`.
If the expected input `getVersionJson` is just one JSON object, your code works.

However, you are getting an array of JSON objects in the input string `getVersionJson`, so you need to use JSONArray class to handle an array of JSON Objects.
This is generally `[ { }, { }, { }, ... ]`

`JSONArray` extends `List`, so it can be iterated to read each `JSONObject` value.

Here is documentation for reference: [Interface JsonArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! I have added explanation.